# Virtual box partitions in windows

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I have installed minikube and Oracle virtual box in windows.Please share where can I find the partitions and files  of Linux virtual box in windows as it is installed in windows system.

Answer (score 2):

Each virtual machine has a virtual hard drive attached to it. It's contained in a single file that was created when you were creating the VM. That file is by default stored in VM's directory, which is in the *VirtualBox VMs* directory in your user directory. So for example:

```
C:\Users\Sailee Das\VirtualBox VMs\My VM\My VM.vdi
```

These files can't be browsed directly because they must emulate a whole drive, not just the filesystem.

If you want to get files off of a virtual drive, consider using shared folders, shared clipboard or drag&drop

Comment: Please share where can I find .docker folder to locate config.json on windows. I am not able to locate it in C:\Users\Sailee Das.

Comment: @SaileeDas Sounds like you've wasted over 2 weeks by [not asking about the problem you actually had](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I've googled _"docker config.json on windows"_ and this came up: [Configure Docker in Windows | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon).